# Scanf only input 1 value out of the 4 & called object is not a function or function pointer error

Tags: c

So I tried to put a program to calculate triangle height here it is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
     float shorty_to_lefty=0.0f , lofty_to_tree=0.0f, lofty=0.0f , shorty=0.0f , arbre=0.0f;

     printf("\nRentrer la distance entre le petit et le grand:" );
     scanf("%0.2f", &shorty_to_lefty);
     printf("\nRentrer la distance entre le grand et l'arbre:" );
     scanf("%0.2f", &lofty_to_tree);
     printf("\nRentrer la taille du petit" );
     scanf("%0.2f", &shorty);
     printf("\nRentrer la taille du grand:" );
     scanf("%0.2f", &lofty);
     
    arbre= lofty+(shorty_to_lefty/lofty_to_tree)(lofty-shorty)/shorty_to_lefty;

    printf("La taille de l'arbre est de %.2f m", arbre);
    


}
```

But the problem is when I launch it the scanf only input 1 value and not the rest ex:
Rentrer la distance entre le petit et le grand:

```
2

Rentrer la distance entre le grand et l'arbre:
Rentrer la taille du petit
Rentrer la taille du grand:La taille de l'arbre est de -1.#J m
```

and in the last float  `arbre= lofty+(shorty_to_lefty/lofty_to_tree)(lofty-shorty)/shorty_to_lefty` when i try to compile I get this error

```
Arbre.c: In function 'main':
Arbre.c:16:34: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
     arbre= lofty+(shorty_to_lefty/lofty_to_tree)(lofty-shorty)/shorty_to_lefty;
```

(there is an arrow under `(shorty_to_lefty/lofty_to_tree)`)

Comment: In `scanf`, change `"%0.2f"` to simple `"%f"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem number 1:

Replace `%0.2f` with `%f`. The `scanf` format specifiers are similar to the ones of `printf` but not identical.

Problem number 2:

```
...lofty_to_tree) (lofty - shorty) ...
                 ^
                 an operator is misssing here, possibly *
```